# Multiple axios get requests React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a React-Redux application and would like to make concurrent API GET requests using axios. I am passing the url as a parameter to the action. How can I achieve it? Its a UI component with different data from API when BU is clicked and when BU is clicked.

[image]
[image]

**Component:**

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { getParallelData } from '../../actions/index';

class BUBGContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getParallelData('https://localhost:3001/reports/bu-list');
    this.props.getParallelData('https://localhost:3001/reports/bg-list');
  }

  updateTabs(i) {
    if (i === 1) {
      this.props.bgTab = true;
      this.props.buTab = false;
    } else {
      this.props.bgTab = false;
      this.props.buTab = true;
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-3">
        <label htmlFor="bu-bg-select">BU/BG:</label>
        <ul id="bu-bg-select-tabs" className="nav nav-tabs">
          <li role="presentation" className={ 'active' } onClick={ this.updateTabs(0) }><a>BU</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" className={ 'active' } onClick={ this.updateTabs(1) }><a>BG</a></li>
        </ul>
        <select name="bubgSelect" id="bu-bg-select" className="form-control">{_.map(this.props.items, (item, index) => <option key={ index }>{item}</option>)}</select>
        <p className="help-block">Hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and click to select multiple items</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  items: state.bubgFetching.data.rows,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ getParallelData }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BUBGContainer);
```

I am not sure how to write an action to achieve the same.

My current action is

```
export const getParallelData = url => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestGetData());
  return axios.get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch(receiveGetData(response.data));
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      dispatch(receiveGetError(response.data));
    });
};

const requestGetData = () => ({ type: ACTION_TYPES.REQ_GET_DATA });

const receiveGetData = json => ({
  type: ACTION_TYPES.RECV_GET_DATA,
  data: json,
});

const receiveGetError = json => ({
  type: ACTION_TYPES.RECV_GET_ERROR,
  data: json,
});
```

My current reducer is

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import * as ACTION_TYPES from '../consts/action_types';

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  data: [],
  error: false,
};

export const isFetchingGet = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = _.cloneDeep(state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.RECV_GET_ERROR: {
      newState.isLoading = false;
      newState.data = action.data;
      newState.error = true;
      return newState;
    }

    case ACTION_TYPES.RECV_GET_DATA: {
      newState.isLoading = false;
      newState.data = action.data;
      newState.error = false;
      return newState;
    }

    case ACTION_TYPES.REQ_GET_DATA: {
      newState.isLoading = true;
      newState.error = false;
      return newState;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529764/6731368) says how to use it but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: What happens when you run your webapp? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: I am not sure how to write an axios.all in my actions. Should I modify my code to fire the api call only when I switch tabs or should it be fetchd when the component mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative with Promise.all focusing on your concurrent request question. Just the related parts:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const list = [ "bu-list, "bg-list" ];
    this.props.getParallelData( list );
}

export const getParallelData = list =>
    async ( dispatch ) => {
        dispatch( requestGetData() );
        try {
            const promiseArray = list.map( el =>
                 axios.get( `https://localhost:3001/reports/${ el }` ) );
            const response = await Promise.all( promiseArray );
            return dispatch( receiveGetData( response ) );
            // and map through response for data, or
            // const [ buList, bgList ] = await Promise.all( promiseArray );
            // return dispatch( receiveGetData( [ buList.data, bgList.data ] ) );
            // or whatever form you want to pass receiveGetData
        } catch ( error ) {
            return dispatch( receiveGetError( error ) );
        }
 };
```

Comment: Throws an error. Invariant violation. Is it because of promise? I also console.log response and it returns undefined.

Comment: I don't know which part of your application you are getting this error but I edited my answer a little bit more about getting the data. You can shape your code by looking Promise.all method. There is an axios.all method but since there is a Promise.all it is not needed. Again, my answer is about doing parallel requests with axios. Maybe you should change other parts of your code according to this method if you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the help devserkan.

Answer (score 0):

You should try redux-thunk or redux-saga middleware. Thunk is the simpler choice.

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

You can also use async/await I find it much more readable than promises.

So here's the deal. Instead of sending objects in your action creators you will be sending functions and redux-thunk automagically does some stuff for you.

You would do something like this:

```
export const getParallelData = url => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const request = axios.get(url);
    try {
      if (response && response.ok) {
        await dispatch({
          type: ACTION_TYPES.REQ_GET_DATA,
          payload: request
        )}
      } catch(err) {
        await dispatch({
         type: ACTION_TYPES.REQ_GET_DATA,
         payload: err.toString()
        )}
      }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do have thunk setup. I will try this and report back. Thanks