# ReactJS: multiple setStates happening asynchronously, state not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Facing an issue where state is not updated, before function (filterAndSort) located in render is fired. I have added a console.log statement within the function, and only one of the states gets updated. My code seems logical to me, as I have set an if condition where function is fired only after setState occurs

Full error message:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.

However, i'm suspecting that because i'm having multiple setStates happening asynchronously.

I'm thinking that perhaps, i need to re-write the componendDidMount to setState for all variables only after all axios requests are fetched. 
[Multiple Axios Requests Into ReactJS State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529553/multiple-axios-requests-into-reactjs-state)

Another solution I think would be to having the returned results of the function stored as a state instead of a variable, then add a componentDidUpdate.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.value > prevState.value) {
    this.filterAndSort();  
  }
}
```

Component

```
class Results extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      races: [],
      arr = []
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    const oneRequest = axios.get(URL_ONE)
                              .then(response =>
                                    response.data.data.map(result => ({...
                                    ))
                                    )
                              .then(results => this.setState({results, isLoading: false}))    

    const twoRequest = axios.get(URL_TWO)
                              .then(response =>
                                response.data.data.map(race => ({...}))
                                )
                          .then(races => this.setDefault(races))

  }

   setDefault = (races) => {
    ........
    this.setState({arr, races, isLoading:false})
  }

  filterAndSort = (races, results) => {
    console.log(races, results)
    .......
  }

  render() {

    const{races, results} = this.state

      if (isLoading == true) {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>Loading...</p>   
          </div>
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <div>
            <BarChart 
              qualData={this.filterAndSort(races, results)} 
              raceData={this.filterAndSort(races, results)} 
              width="1200" 
              height="500" />

          </div>
          );
        }
      }

}

export default Results;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a number of things that come to my mind.

First, you set the isLoading to false only when you have one of two pieces of data, whichever comes first, thus the render method will at some point call your function with either empty races or results.
Another thing, you are asynchronously calling setState. By the time the request is finished your component may not exist any more thus it will try to update a non existing component and fail with that error.

For the first issue, one possible solution is to have two isLoading-variables for both results and races.

For the second issue (setState called on an unmountedComponent), its a bit more complicated, because you need to somehow cancel the request. I recommend reading more on this, the general advice is to move your data out of the components using a library like redux. If you google `cancel promise on unmount` you will find discussion on this. You can also deal with it using an "isMounted" variable, which will work as an ugly patch.

So, as soon as request one (or two) is completed, setState is called, the component is then re-rendered. The isLoading is now true so filterAndSort is called with results (or races) but not both because the second request is still pending.

Finally, in your render method your isLoading needs to be first defined (i assume its ok in your code but not in the question) and the is True comparison can be better put as

`if (isLoading) {` instead of `if (isLoading == True) {`

Answer (score 0):

You're right. When making multiple requests its always best practice to wait for them *all* to resolve before moving forward. For that you can use the `Promise` library which is built into ES6. Also, for fetching of data its best practice, so far as i've seen, to do it in `componentWillMount()`. I'll also add that the context of `this` changes when inside an async function. So in your `componentWillMount()`:

```
let promiseArr = [axios.get(URL_ONE), axios.get(URL_TWO)];
let _this = this;
Promise.all(promiseArr)
  .then((resp) => {
    // Call _this.setState() here. Response from URL_ONE  
    // will be available in resp.data[0] and URL_TWO in resp.data[1]
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Also, in your constructor:

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      races: [],
      arr = []
      isLoading: true
    };
    this.setDefault = this.setDefault.bind(this);
    this.filterAndSort = this.filterAndSort.bind(this);
}
```

Using `.bind` to make sure that the context of `this` is referrering to the current instance of the class when calling those methods.

I think after doing those things that error will go away. Hope that helps.